# understand Korn shell numeric statements

Tags: unix, ksh

Have lot of questions in ksh as i struggle to understand the code. here is one which i couldnt find the answer

```
function prn_msg
{
   print "command usage: "
   print "   $COMMAND -i<id> -d<date>"
    exit $BADOPTIONS
} 1>&2
```

I understood that it prints the text to a `stderr` output and exits the shell execution with the return code in `BADOPTIONS`. 
but don't understand what does the `1>&2` do

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/818255/in-the-shell-what-does-21-mean for explanation of Unix file handles 1 and 2.

Comment: always wonder why they made it so difficult to understand :)

Answer (score 1):

In the comment OP asks for a simple answer.
The link given by @Bernard tells more, two simple answers are:

Output to the screen is divided in (1) normal output and (2) error output. 1>&2 is a method to reroute normal output to the error output.

and

It is a way to make the output of that function being written to stderr, which can be filtered later.

Note: I never use 1>&2 but use 2>&1 a lot. That way you can redirect both to a file or /dev/null.